# Jquery UI Dialog Weird Behavior in Firefox - Whole screen becomes non-clickable on second overlay

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, modal-dialog

I have two links that show up two modal dialogs. These dialogs are static divs in the html of the page with their own ids.

When I click the first link, the first dialog shows up and behaves correctly. But when I click the second link, the whole screen grays out and everything becomes unclickable, including the second dialog. It happens also the other way around, clicking the second link, and then the first link.

This problems occurs only in Firefox but not in IE.

Any ideas why this is happening in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

It really sounds weird. The idea of a `modal` dialog actually IS to gray/block the background while the dialog is shown.
So I'm wondering how do you call the `second` dialog while another `modal` dialog is opened?

If you call an UI dialog with

```
modal: true
```

it should be impossible to interact with your inputs as long as that dialog is open.

Comment: I only click on the second link after closing the first window. When the second modal dialog opens up, everything in the browser is non-clickable, including the modal window.

Comment: this one is very late post indeed, but yes i am also facing the same problem,but i am having only one div for modal dialog when i click it freezes entire screen, irrespective of i.e. or firefox

Comment: I would encourage you guys to create a jsfiddle.net example with your markup and code.

Comment: I have the same issue in FF Quantum 68 with JQUery UI 1.11.4. Sometimes second, third, fourth opening will lock the whole screen. Anyone ever find a solution to this?